# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Int32'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Getting the error when asking for equal type of string in

```
var orderTransferFromDb = await context.OrderTransfer.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t =>
t.ToMemberMobilePhone.ToUpperInvariant().Equals(mobilePhone.ToUpperInvariant()));

public async Task<bool> UpdateOrderTransferToMemberId(string mobilePhone, string memberid)
{
    if (mobilePhone != null)
    {
        using (var context = ContextManager.ClubContext())
        {
            var orderTransferFromDb = await context.OrderTransfer.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.ToMemberMobilePhone.ToUpperInvariant().Equals(mobilePhone.ToUpperInvariant()));
            if (orderTransferFromDb != null)
            {
                context.Attach(orderTransferFromDb);
                orderTransferFromDb.ToMemberId = memberid;
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("MobilePhone is null. (UpdteOrderTransferByEmail)");     
}
```

[image: ordertransfer model]

[image: sql]

The arguments are both `string`, and in SQL Server `nvarchar(13)`

What can cause it?

Comment: show the complete error message

Comment: Are you using entity framework ?

Comment: your string includes numbers?

Comment: what if you remove ToUpperInvariant() ?

Comment: @AmeerPappay the string here only numbers, and without ToUpperInvariant() same error

Comment: if its only numbers why cant u tak e type as int?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your code. You need to double check your context whether is mapped correctly with your object.

To Compare string without case, use this

```
var orderTransferFromDb = await context.OrderTransfer.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => string.Equals(t.ToMemberMobilePhone, mobilePhone, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```